# Finding the value of $|z|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z$ is a **non-real number** such that,
$$\frac{1+z+z^2}{1-z+z^2}$$
is purely real. Find the value of $|z|$.

> Hello everyone!
>   For this question, when I set $\displaystyle{a}$=$\dfrac{1+z+z^2}{1-z+z^2}$ and used $a=\bar{a}$ but it got very messy. Is there any alternate, elegant approach?
>   Thanks to take your time to read my question.

Comment: The expression is purely real for every real value of $z$, so the condition is insufficient to determine the modulus.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying both sides in your definition of $a$ by $1-\bar z+\bar z^2$?

Comment: @MarkBennet Good grief! How did I manage to miss that observation?

Comment: No, that is a common misconception. Real numbers are complex, too. Should it have been $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$? (I am not at all sure that my advice above is useful, however.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Given:** $\dfrac{1+z+z^2}{1-z+z^2}\in\mathbb{R}$

$\implies 1+\dfrac{2z}{1-z+z^2}\in\mathbb{R}$

$\implies \dfrac{1-z+z^2}{z}\in\mathbb{R}$

$\implies z+\dfrac{1}{z}-1 \in\mathbb{R}$

$\implies z+\dfrac{1}{z}\in\mathbb{R}$

$\implies z+\dfrac{1}{z}=\bar{z}+{\dfrac{1}{\bar{z}}}$

$\implies z-\bar{z}=\dfrac{z-\bar{z}}{z\bar{z}}$

$\implies z\bar{z}=1$ [ Since $z\in\mathbb{C/R}$ ]

$\implies |z|^{2}=1$

$\implies |z|=\boxed{1}$

Comment: I don't see how $z+1/z=\bar z+1/\bar z$ implies $z\bar z=1$.

Comment: @ajotatxe That's because it doesn't. But if $z$ is assumed not real, it does. That requires an argument, however.

Comment: @ajotatxe I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!

Comment: No, it can't be right, since $z$ could be (almost) any real number.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I meant only complex numbers i.e, non real but I do not know its symbol. Can you please tell me the symbol for non reals. Thanks!

Comment: $z-\bar z$ can be cancelled iff $z\notin\Bbb R$.

Comment: There is no single symbol for non-real complex numbers. But see my third comment to the question.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1+z+z^2}{1-z+z^2}\in\Bbb R&\iff1+\frac{2z}{z^2-z+1}\in\Bbb R\\
&\iff\frac z{z^2-z+1}\in\Bbb R\\
&\iff \frac{z^2-z+1}z\in\Bbb R\\
&\iff z+\frac1z\in\Bbb R
\end{align}$$

Now, the equation $z+\frac 1z=a$, for $a\in \Bbb R$, has this solution:

$$z=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}}2$$

For $|a|<2$ this solution is not real, and
$$|z|^2=\frac{a^2}4+\frac{4-a^2}4=\frac44=1$$

But for $|a|\ge 2$, $z$ spans the whole set of real numbers.